# publishing website to the server

Tags: asp.net

sir,

I have copied the asp.net website in to www root of server from my local pc.then created a website in iis of server.Then publish the website from my local host to the server iis http path .But when browse the website is not displaying.

In my local host I could run the project in visual studio.But after copying it to server wwwroot or(E:)I can not run the project.
This message is showing " can not be opened because its project type is not supported by this version of application"
How can I solve this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do I want to install visual studio in server.As I am not familiar with server,help is greatly aprreatiated

Comment: In local host and server VS 2008 IS USING.BUT I can not load the project in server.the project file cannot be loaded msg is coming

Answer (score 0):

You must have convert your web site to application.

GO to iis-> Click on Site Folder and Expend it -> Select your website folder-> right click on it -> and Choose convert to Application and provide the further information.

That`s it.

Comment: convert to application is not showing on the right click